# Subtract days with ColeDateTimeSpan to a ColeDateTime

Tags: c++, coledatetime

I have to update an old date class for one of my assignment and I'm stuck on this function I have to redo.

The function needs to return a Bool if the operation is possible.

What I want to do is subtract days with ColeDateTimeSpan to a ColeDateTime

I know I can do something like this :

```
int i = 2;    
COleDateTime time_DT = COleDateTime(2014, 2, 20, 0, 0, 0);
COleDateTimeSpan time_SP = COleDateTimeSpan(i);
time_DT = time_DT - time_SP;
cout << time_DT.GetDay() << endl;
```

In this case my function would return true;

```
long i = 999999999999;    
COleDateTime time_DT = COleDateTime(2014, 2, 20, 0, 0, 0);
COleDateTimeSpan time_SP = COleDateTimeSpan(i);
time_DT = time_DT - time_SP;
cout << time_DT.GetDay() << endl;
```

In this case my function would return false instead of crashing

This is what I have so far:

```
bool Date::addDays(long days)
{
    bool bRet = true;
    COleDateTimeSpan ts(m_time); //m_time being my COleDateTime
    COleDateTimeSpan tl(days);

    if (tl > ts)
    {
        bRet = false;
        return bRet;
    }
    else
    {
        return bRet;
    }   
}
```

Thanks!

EDIT : I meant subtract....

Answer (score 2):

I know it is too late for your assignment, however, others might find it useful.

```
bool Date::AddDays(long days)
{
    // Copy the original value to temporary variable so that it is not lost when subtraction results 
    // in invalid time.
    COleDateTime dtTime(m_time);

    // Check the time for validity before performing subtraction.
    if(dtTime.GetStatus() != COleDateTime::valid )
        return false;

    // Check the input for valid value range. Must be positive value.
    if(days < 0)
        return false;

    // Use that constructor of 'COleDateTimeSpan' which takes days as input.
    COleDateTimeSpan tsDays(days, 0,0,0);   // (Days, Hours, Min, Sec).

    // Perform the subtraction.
    dtTime = dtTime - tsDays;

    // Check if the subtraction has resulted into valid time.
    if(dtTime.GetStatus() != COleDateTime::valid )
        return false;

    // Copy the result from temporary variable to class member.
    m_time = dtTime;

    return true;
}
```